# How to interact with a foreign key in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, java

I have been working on a database for sometime now and i got stocked a particular section. I am trying to write a code to control the foreign key column in a database. mysql is the back-end and Java is the front-end.
Already worked on the faculty table with this code :

```
try {
        String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/accomodation";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "";

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,username,password);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    String Query = "INSERT INTO faculty( Name, DeanName, Email) values ('"
                  + facCombo.getSelectedItem() + "', '" 
                  + deanTF.getText() + "', '" 
                  + facmailTF.getText() + "')";
    stmt.executeUpdate(Query);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Inserted Successfully", "Status", 
                                  JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

} catch (Exception e) {

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "incorrect");
}
```

The database is linked as faculty to department and the department has the foreign key referencing the faculty table but have tried writing a query referencing it all to no avail. 
Will be grateful if someone can help me out.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Not related to question, but an advise to use prepared statements in case someone tries to do SQL Injection: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-mysql-insert-example-preparedstatement